# use FPM options in EASYBUILD for pakaging

Tags: fpm

I make rpm packages by easybuild below command

```
 module load fpm
 eb --package Perl-5.20.1-GCC-4.9.2-bare.eb --robot
```

now suppose I want to use some of FPM options(you can see them by "fpm -h") . for example by  "--rpm-group" in fpm I can set a group for the installed packages. How can I use these options by eb?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify option for the packaging tool being used (in this case FPM) via the --package-tool-options command line option for 'eb', so:

```
eb --package Perl-5.20.1-GCC-4.9.2-bare.eb --robot --package-tool-options "--rpm-group"
```

Or, if you want to do this every time, you can define the `$EASYBUILD_PACKAGE_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable:

```
export EASYBUILD_PACKAGE_TOOL_OPTIONS='--rpm-group'
```

This will be picked up by the `eb` command, see the output of `eb --show-config` after defining `$EASYBUILD_PACKAGE_TOOL_OPTIONS`